# How to find match data in table <td> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

In table data, I want to highlight one column as active,
so I would like to find a specific value in table `<tr>`.

For example, in temp value I get - "8h"
I have to find 8h value in  one `<tr>` and make that as active  that column.

```
var temp = substr[0] + " h";
                var MyRows = $("#tbl_forecast tr:nth-child(2)")
                for (var i = 0; i < MyRows.length; i++) {                    
                    if (temp.trim() == $("#tb_forecast tr:nth-child(2)").find('td:eq(i)').html())
                    {                        
                        $("#tbl_forecast td:nth-child(i)").addClass("td_active")
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector for finding data inside `td`, try following code :

```
var temp = substr[0] + " h";
// or use nth-child for second row selector
// $("#tbl_forecast tr:nth-child(2)")
// as below code will iterate all rows and find `td`
$('#tbl_forecast tr').find("td:contains('"+temp.trim()+"')").addClass('active');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/3entt0ea/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to get the td and **[`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** to get the index of that
2. Now using that index add class to the column with the help of **[`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** selector

```js
var temp = substr[0] + " h";
var MyRows = $("#tbl_forecast tr:nth-child(2)"),rows=$("#tbl_forecast tr");
var index = MyRows.find('td').filter(function() {
  return temp.trim() == $(thid).text();
}).index();
rows.find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
```